# Varchar(max) column not allowed to be a Primary Key in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Varchar(max) column not allowed to be a Primary Key in SQL Server.

What is the max length of a varchar type that can be made a primary key.

This might be a bad practice, but came across the situation.

Comment: Why do you not have an ID column?

Comment: You aren't using varchar(max) for anything except fields that you expect to be over 8000 characters are you? You will have performance issues if so due to the indexing issues.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

900 bytes is the max length for a primary key, this is a bad idea in my opinion, why don't you use a surrogate key instead?

Answer (score 6):

This question has already been answered [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2043335/1339383); the short answer is that an index field cannot exceed 900 bytes. That said, it's generally a bad idea to use a long VARCHAR field as an index for myriad reasons such as efficiency and maintainability.

Answer (score 3):

The primary key is used in all other indexes to identify rows.  Having a potentially multi-megabyte value as a key makes very little sense, hence the limit in general on total bytes in any key.